# Percentage of point features within polygon boundaries R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, plot

I am trying to create a histogram with the percentage of a concentration of points in a specific area. My data is someting like this:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\myrtos")
getwd()
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(Rcpp)
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
pottery <- read.csv (file="potter.csv", header=TRUE)
stonetools <- read.csv (file="stonetool.csv", header=TRUE)
stonewght <- read.csv (file="stoneweights.csv", header=TRUE)
rooms <- readOGR (dsn="shp", layer="rooms")
rooms <- as(rooms,"owin")
```

I would like to show the percentages of each category (pottery, stonetools...) in my window of analysis, "rooms", but I am not sure how we plot data like this that it is not numeric.

PS. csv files include coordinates and information on each object, like material or purpose of use. You can find my data [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11sRtApvnZr3nbBGFcR7R898RUYDQu_Mn?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you share your data or a portion of your data? It's a good practice to do that so people can reproduce your code and help you.

Comment: Thank you. I added a link to my data

Comment: Do you know what coordinate system (CRS) your data are in? Also, since your 'rooms' layer have point geometry rather than polygon, you will need to define a boundary around them, so do you know how you would like to go about that? You could create equal sized buffers around all of them or do something more sophisticated

Comment: The CRS is the Greek Grid. Ok I'll try what you suggest

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the points to display in the correct location (somewhere in Greece, presumably) using EPSG:2100 (https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/ggrs87-greek-grid/). Do you know what the EPSG code for the CRS should be?

Comment: Hmm, I am not quite sure what the problem is, but the EPSG:2100 is correct. But, the map was not generated with original coordinates from the begininng, so after the projection, althought it should be displayed in Greece it is not

Answer (score 2):

You can find which points fall inside the polygons and append the results to a new dataframe, then reshape that dataframe to make it more suitable for visualization such as:

```
#dependencies
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

#set working directory
setwd('./path/to/vector/data')

#load in rooms layer
rooms <- readOGR('rooms.shp')

#load in points and convert to spatialpoints
stools <- st_read("stonetool.csv", options=c("X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=XCoord","Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=YCoord"))
st_crs(stools) <- st_crs(rooms)
stools <- as_Spatial(stools)

sweights <- st_read("stoneweights.csv", options=c("X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=XCoord","Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=YCoord"))
st_crs(sweights) <- st_crs(rooms)
sweights <- as_Spatial(sweights)

pottery <- st_read("potter.csv", options=c("X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=XCoord","Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=YCoord"))
st_crs(pottery) <- st_crs(rooms)
pottery <- as_Spatial(pottery)

#find points within polygons
stools_within <- over(stools, rooms)
sweights_within <- over(sweights, rooms)
pottery_within <- over(pottery, rooms)

#create new blank dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(as.factor(rooms@data$Rooms))
names(df) <- c('Room')

#make new df from each 'within' layer 
df1 <- as.data.frame(table(stools_within$Rooms))
names(df1) <- c('Room', 'stools_in')
df1$stools_sum <- length(stools)
df1$stools_pct <- df1$stools_in / df1$stools_sum *100

df2 <- as.data.frame(table(sweights_within$Rooms))
names(df2) <- c('Room', 'sweights_in')
df2$sweights_sum <- length(sweights)
df2$sweights_pct <- df2$sweights_in / df2$sweights_sum *100

df3 <- as.data.frame(table(sweights_within$Rooms))
names(df3) <- c('Room', 'pottery_in')
df3$pottery_sum <- length(pottery)
df3$pottery_pct <- df3$pottery_in / df3$pottery_sum *100

#merge 'within' dataframes to new df with rooms
df <- merge(df,df1, by='Room', all.x = T)
df <- merge(df,df2, by='Room', all.x = T)
df <- merge(df,df3, by='Room', all.x = T)

#replace NA values with 0
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

#subset dataframe to include columns of interest
df_clean <- df[,c('Room', 'stools_pct', 'sweights_pct', 'pottery_pct')]

#convert to long format
df_long <- melt(data = df_clean, 
                id.vars = c("Room"),
                variable.name = "type",
                value.name = "percentage")
```

It's not a histogram, but you can visualize the percentages in a grouped bar chart using ggplot 2:

```
library(ggplot2)

#remove 0 values for plotting
df_long[df_long==0] <- NA
df_long <- na.omit(df_long)

#subset data by specific Rooms
subset <- df_long[df_long$Room %in% list("A02", "A03", "A04", "A15"),]


# Grouped barplot using ggplot2
ggplot(subset,                                      
       aes(x = Room,
           y = percentage,
           fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge") +
  theme_classic()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! it works perfectly. Do you know how can I set only a cluster of rooms as a window of analysis area? So I can get a clearer view on the data (E.g. R81, R82, R91). It would also work if you could let me know how to make the y axis larger, so I can see the room IDs easier

Comment: No problem. Added line to subset data with list of room IDs. You'll need to import tidyr as a dependency now.

Comment: Million thanks! So now I interpret the percentage as the presence of each category in the specified area right? So if pottery is at 1.0 in a room then this means 10%?

Comment: No these have already been converted to percentages so 1 =1% of the features from that points layer

Comment: So if it's 1 it is 1% of the pottery in total. Many many thanks